# Enabling SSL in intranet for Tomcat Server with .pfx file and public key

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have got .pfx file and public key of certificate. I have to configure my tomcat server to enable SSL.
I am using the connector configuration below:

```
<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"     
    maxThreads="150"     
    enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"    
    acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"     
    SSLEnabled="true"      
    SSLCertificateFile="${catalina.base}/conf/domaincertificate.pfx"    
    SSLCertificateKeyFile="${catalina.base}/conf/domaincertificatekey.pem" />
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question. Whats the error thrown etc...

Comment: At Browser I am getting this: 
This page can’t be displayed      
 •Make sure the web address https://domainname.net is correct.    
 •Look for the page with your search engine.     
 •Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Comment: You need the private key. The public key is in the certificate.